# Шифрование файла

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Доброе утро! Мне необходимо зашифровать обычный текстовый файл... Структура FileInfo позволяет это сделать парой строчек кода... Но по какой-то причине я не понимаю результат шифрования:

```
         FileInfo ^ info2 = gcnew FileInfo("D:\\CountIn.txt");
         info2 -> Encrypt();
```

После вызова функции файл остается в исходном виде, за исключением его название, которое поменяло цвет на зеленый с черного... Пользователь под другой учетной записью так же может просматривать содержимое этого файла. Подскажите, в чем причина?

Comment: В том что оба пользователя - администраторы ПК и имеют доступ к хранилищу ключей

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, Я передаю по почте этот файл стороннему человеку на другой ПК, за 2к км, и он открывает его с исходным содержимым, что это значит?

Comment: Что вы перед передачей файла либо добавляете его в архив либо используете иной софт который в курсе про EFS и достает содержимое файла.(т.е. файлы перед отправкой получаются расшифроваными)

Comment: Вероятно файл автоматически расшифровывается, когда вы к нему обращаетесь, чтобы переслать. Если вам нужно в зашифрованном виде отсылать данные, используйте средства из [System.Security.Cryptography](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю что делает эта функция, она шифрует файл средствами EFS, то есть делает то же самое, что можно сделать правым кликом на файле и выбором `Properties / General / Advanced / Encrypt contents`.

Файл действительно шифруется (что и показывает изменение цвета в окне Windows Explorer), но он прозрачно расшифровывается при любом обращение, если в данной системе установлен сертификат, которым он зашифрован. А вот если вы удалите сертификат, переустановите или сделаете апгрейд системы, или просто перенесете диск на другой компьютер, то обнаружите, что файл недоступен.

В общем, я бы посоветовал почитать про EFS (Encrypted File System), чтобы при случае не поиметь сюрприз. Как минимум почитайте как сделать бэкап сертификата.

Comment: Вы плохо понимаете как работает EFS =) "Сертификат"( он же ключ шифрования) по умолчанию доступен только пользователю который зашифровал файл и всем Администраторм ПК, поведение по умолчанию можно изменить настройкой политик(например отключить доступы у администратора), так же можно изменить хранилище сертификата(перенести его например на токен). При "апдейте" системы - с сертификатом ничего не случится(именно при апдейте а не переустановке).

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, рад, что вы понимаете лучше меня, но все, что вы тут расписали, не имеет отношения к заданному вопросу. Из вопроса совершенно очевидно, что ТС интересовало прямое шифрование файла, а не разграничение доступа, пусть даже формально с применением шифрования. Так что детали этого разграничения вряд ли важны для ответа и я не вижу смысла грузить ТС не относящейся к делу заумью.

Comment: Хоть формально хоть виртуально EFS это конкретно шифрование файла, а не разграничение доступа, разграничение доступа это "права NTFS" если что. А автор явно указал что у него **"файл открывается под другим пользователем"** что подразумевало именно шифрование под одним пользователем. А теперь по второй части - **если мой комментарий не имеет отношения к вопросу, то какое отношение к нему имеет ваш ответ?** ибо он о том же самом EFS, но еще и с недочетами(на которые я вам указал).

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, если знаете как ответить лучше, нажмите кнопку "Ответ" и ответьте. Не надо объяснять мне что такое EFS и права NTFS. Расскажите это ТС, раз уж считаете, что ваши разъяснения необходимы.

Comment: Это вопрос автора: **Пользователь под другой учетной записью так же может просматривать содержимое этого файла. Подскажите, в чем причина?** 
Это мой комментарий: **В том что оба пользователя - администраторы ПК**, Я не вижу тут вопроса на который стоило бы отвечать, помочь автору - достаточно комментария.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, ну а мне-то ваши объяснения зачем. тем более в такой хамской форме? С EFS и NTFS я достаточно работал. Еще вопрос кто из нас "плохо понимает", так что поменьше высокомерия.

Comment: Я вам не хамил, а уточнил моменты в которых вы ошибались(ошибаетесь), и сделано это было в первую очередь для автора вопроса...